# Cant move files to trash

Tags: trash

somehow I cannot move files to trash. The strange thing is, that it works on the desktop-folder, but in other folders it doesn't. What a tried is a

```
sudo chown -R wegsehen /home/wegsehen/*
```

But nothing changed.

Comment: see [this bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+bug/192629).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo chown -R wegsehen:wegsehen /home/wegsehen
```

No /* on end of line maybe?

Comment: No change. I can delete files, but not move to trash. I can move them to desktop and then delete to trash.

Answer (score 0):

try this out, making sure you own your own trash bin.

```
sudo chown wegsehen:wegsehen ~/.local/share/Trash
```

You also may want to make sure you own all your files in home

```
sudo chown wegsehen:wegsehen -R ~/*
```

And yet still if your using a separate data partition make sure you have ownership of said partition, replacing '/Path/to/your/data/partition' with the actual path to your data partition.

```
sudo chown wegsehen:wegsehen -R /Path/to/your/data/partition
```

And yet even still, you want to make sure your data or even home partition is mounted properly by editing your fstab file

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Once your fstab is opened your line for the mounting of the data/home partition should look something like this...

```
/dev/sda5 /media/data   ext4  auto,users,rw,noatime   0    0
```

paying attention to 'auto,users,rw,noatime' the rest of your fstab info will obviously look quite different.